# Mocking method in class called through Multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, multiprocessing

I am writing a python tcp proxy: whenever a connection gets established from the client, the proxy establishes the connection to the server, and transparently forwards both streams. Additionally, when the packet being forwarded has some conditions, I want to have it parsed and have that sent to another server.

This is the contents of my unittest:

```py
class TestParsing(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.patcher = patch('EnergyDataClient.EnergyDataClient', autospec=True)
        self.EC_mock = self.patcher.start()
        EnergyAgent.EC = self.EC_mock()
        EnergyAgent.GP = MyParser.MyParser()
        self.server = multiprocessing.Process(target=tcp_server, args=(1235,))
        self.gp = multiprocessing.Process(target=EnergyAgentRunner, args=(1234, 1235))
        self.server.start()
        self.gp.start()

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.patcher.stop()
        self.server.terminate()
        self.gp.terminate()

        while self.server.is_alive() or self.gp.is_alive():
            sleep(0.1)

    def test_parsemessage(self):
        # start the client process, and wait until done
        result = tcp_client(1234, correct_packets['DATA04']['request'])
        self.assertEqual(correct_packets['DATA04']['request'], result)
        EnergyAgent.EC.post.assert_called_once()
```

I want to validate that the 'post' method on the object EC is called with the contents I expect to have intercepted... but, as that object is on another process, mocking seems not to be helping. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is happening here. When calling multiprocessing.Process, python is spawning a new process using fork(), that produces a copy of the memory pages on the child process. That is the reason because I can patch the EnergyAgent.GP and works (as that object is only read from that point on, and we do not require it back at the main process) and EnergyAgent.EC **does not** work: The mocked object gets successfully updated on the *child process*, but the parent never realizes that.

Comment: Hi @chronos, did you find way to solve above problem? I am also trying to mock method called by aiomultiprocess.worker process. Asked my question here at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77707418/mocking-function-executed-by-aiomultiprocess-worker-python

Comment: @VishalSahu, No, I did not. I finally moved on to another project.