# Mocking function executed by aiomultiprocess Worker Python

Tags: python, mocking

I'm looking to mock method called by `aiomultiprocess.Worker`(which essentially create separate process to run provided function). Normal mocking works when code is executed in same process(case 1) but not when in Worker process(case2). Here is code structure:

module/handler.py:

```
from aiomultiprocess import Worker
from module.handler_util import solve_internal

class handler:
  async def solve(self) -> int:
    """
    # case 1
    return await solve_internal() # this works fine
    """
    # case 2
    return await Worker(target=solve_internal, args=()).join()
```

module/handler_util.py:

```
async def solve_internal() -> int:
  return 2
```

module/test.py:

```
@patch('module.handler.solve_internal')
def test_handler(solve_mock:AsyncMock):
  solve_mock.return_value = 5
  h = handler()
  assert(h.solve() == 5)
  # following fails when handler processes solve() via Worker in case 2
  solve_mock.assert_called_once()
```

It works in case 1 because module calling solve_internal there is handler which is mocked correctly by test. However, how do I mock it when call is made by Worker in case2. I am guessing there must be way to patch them like `@patch('aiomultiprocess.worker.solve_internal')` etc.